# Gimp won't start: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

Tags: 18.04, snap, gimp, ubuntu-minimal

All out of a sudden, gimp refuses to start. The following messages are printed at the console:

```
/snap/gimp/40/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /home/mike/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.locale” has path “/system/locale/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy” has path “/system/proxy/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.http” has path “/system/proxy/http/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.https” has path “/system/proxy/https/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp” has path “/system/proxy/ftp/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
Warning: Schema “org.gnome.system.proxy.socks” has path “/system/proxy/socks/”.  Paths starting with “/apps/”, “/desktop/” or “/system/” are deprecated.
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Gtk-Message: 20:35:18.485: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Cannot open display:
```

Do you have any ideas what could have caused this? Or how to repair it? Gimp used to work on the day it was first installed.

**Edit:** 
This happens on the minimal Ubuntu installation.

Gnome's Calculator app also stopped working all out of a sudden. Looks like one of the most recent updates broke something here.

Thank you.

Comment: @George Udosen: Yes, it's the same error message, but the proposed fix doesn't work in in this case. (Both libatk-adaptor and libgail-common have already been installed.) Also, gimp just broke with one of the most recent Ubuntu updates. It was working fine immediately after installation - which was about three weeks ago. So no, not really a duplicate. But thank you for sharing it anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like some permissions got messed up. In case it happens to you, try the following:

Launch **Ubuntu Software**, search for **Gimp** and display the details of the list entry that is marked as *installed*. Hit the permissions button and grant all permissions. After that, gimp was working fine again.