# When launching firefox, get error Not loading module "atk-bridge"

Tags: firefox, gtk

If I run `firefox` in terminal then firefox works just fine, but I get the error message:

```
Gtk-Message: 10:54:24.330: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
```

How do I get rid of this error message?

There are other questions on StackExchange sites which ask about this same error message, but they do not fix my issue. Things I've tried which don't fix the problem:

- Installing `snapd` and `snapd-desktop-integration` (see [here](https://snapcraft.io/install/snapd-desktop-integration/ubuntu)), and running `sudo snap refresh snapd-desktop-integration --stable` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406844/not-loading-module-atk-bridge-the-functionality-is-provided-by-gtk-natively))
- Installing `libcanberra` packages (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406844/not-loading-module-atk-bridge-the-functionality-is-provided-by-gtk-natively) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143858/gimp-giving-me-failed-to-load-module-atk-bridge-canberra-gtk-module))
- Installing `libatk-adaptor` (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099824/terminal-warning-gti-message-failed-to-load-module-atk-bridge) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143858/gimp-giving-me-failed-to-load-module-atk-bridge-canberra-gtk-module))
- [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062662/gimp-wont-start-gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-atk-bridge) is irrelevant
- [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer seems too old to be relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If firefox is working fine, why dont just supress the error message ?
Lets make an environment variable, first go to your .bashrc file `nano ~/.bashrc` then add this at the end of the file `export GTK_DEBUG=interactive` save and exit, apply it `source ~/.bashrc` now it should work, if not you can also use this one `export G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all`.